# Loop through a particular database and getting ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy with each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to loop through the all the team_members for a particular user and show all their answers at a particular page.Instead of showing all the answers for the team_members of a particular user. It's showing me this.

```
Updates

  Prashanth

<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Answer:0x00000001b2ce28>

  Sai

 <ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Answer:0x00000001b21230>
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_members
end
```

TeamMember model

```
class TeamMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers
end
```

Answer Model

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team_member
end
```

This is my answers/index.html file where I loop through all the answers for a particular team member.

```
<h1>Updates</h1>

<% if @answers.count > 0 %>
<% @answers.each do |answer| %>
  <blockquote>
    <p><%= answer.name %></p>
    <small><%= answer.answers %></small>
  </blockquote>
<% end %>
<% else %>
<p><em>Oops, doesn't look like there are any posts yet.</em></p>
<% end %>
```

Here is my schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141118133533) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "answers", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "answer"
    t.integer  "team_member_id"
`  `t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
  end

  add_index "answers", ["team_member_id"], name: "index_answers_on_team_member_id", using: :btree

  create_table "team_members", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "user_id"
 end

 add_index "team_members", ["user_id"], name: "index_team_members_on_user_id", using: :btree

 create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

Here is my AnswersController

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @answers = current_user.team_members.each do |team_member|
         team_member.answers.all
    end

  end



end
```

What should I change in the index.html or the asnwers controller to get the list of answers?

Comment: Post your controller code. so we can see where @answers is coming from

Comment: Added Answers controller

Comment: Let me try to make the things clear: You want to list all the answers that belongs to your current_users's team_members?

Comment: Yes. Apologies for not being explicit about it.

Answer (score 0):

If your answer.answers is an array of strings, then simply change the view line to :

```
<small><%= answer.answers.join ', ' %></small>
```

If answer.answers contains records with a field containing the actual answer string, then use (if that field is called 'body', otherwise change body to the field name):

```
<small><%= answer.answers.map(&:body) %></small>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @answers = Answers.where(team_member: current_user.team_members)
  end
end
```

and in your view:

```
<% if @answers.count > 0 %>
  <% @answers.each do |answer| %>
    <blockquote>
      <p><%= answer.name %></p>
      <small><%= answer.answer %></small>
    </blockquote>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <p><em>Oops, doesn't look like there are any posts yet.</em></p>
<% end %>
```